# How does a Pytorch neural network load dataset into GPU

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gpu

When loading a dataset into the GPU for training, would a Pytorch NN load the entire dataset or just the batch?

I have a 33GB dataset that fits comfortably on my normal RAM (64GB) but i only have a 16GB of GPU RAM (T4). As long as Pytorch only loads one batch at a time into the GPU, that should work fine without any memory problems?

Comment: One thing to note is that the dataset stored in your drive (33GB) is usually in compressed form (like png or jpg for images). And when you load that as a Tensor (either on GPU or CPU), they will be in uncompressed form and hence will take a much larger space than the disk space. So, your comparisons of disk memory and GPU memory/system RAM don't seem to be valid. Rather you should try loading one batch as a tensor and check the RAM usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load one batch of data at a time into GPU. You should use data loader to fetch a batch of data and also initialize a torch device instance to use GPU.

You can check the following tutorial. It uses data loader to get data as batches and load them to GPU by using torch device.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html